# Completeness of the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, complete-spaces

I have the following problem:

> Let $J:=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})\cap[0,1]$ be the irrational numbers in the intervall $[0,1]$. Show that J can't be written as $J=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ with closed sets $F_n\subset[0,1]$

I guess I can use the "Baire category theorem", which says:

> If a complete metric space $X$ is written as an union $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ of countable closed sets $F_n$, at least one $F_n$ contains a closed ball.

My problem is now that $J$ isn't complete, because there should be a cauchy-sequence, which converges to $0$, but $0\notin J$. How can I proof my problem without the Baire category theorem?

Another problem is, that the Baire category theorem specifies that the amount of closed sets is countable. Can someone give me a hint how to solve these two problems?

The rest would be simple because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so in every ball in a $F_n$ is a rational number and so $J=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ isn't possible. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use $J$, use $[0,1]$ as your complete metric space:

Suppose that it is possible to write $J=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n$ as a countable union of closed sets. Each of these sets is nowhere dense because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is countable, we can also write $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$ as a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets, namely the points of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. Putting these together, it follows that
$$ [0,1]=\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n\Big)\cup\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n\Big)$$
is a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets, which contradicts the Baire category theorem.

Comment: Here you asume that J can be written as a countable union. But that's not exactly what's asked for. In my problem J is a union of maybe uncountable closed sets. Isn't that a problem? Also why can't the $F_n$ be simply all single irrational numbers? A single element as a set is closed. So if the $F_n$ are not necessary countable why can't you write J as such an union?

Comment: In your problem statement you wrote $J=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n$, which is a countable union. Of course $J$ can be written as an uncountable union of its points, which are closed sets. Note that the phrase "countable union" means that there are countably many sets, not that the sets themselves are countable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't write down the Baire theorem correctly:
>If a complete metric space $X$ is written as a countable union $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ of closed sets $F_n$, at least one $F_n$ contains a closed ball.

Also, where did I write that J has to be a "countable" union?
The specific problem here is, that two requirements("completeness/countable union") are not given in this example, so I have to show that the Baire theorem doesn't work here.

If J can be written as an uncountable union of single elements, then why doesn't that contradict the statement I want to proof?

Comment: The highlighted text in the question includes the phrase "Show that $J$ can't be written as $J=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n$". This is what I was referring to.

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't have to be a countable union, so it shouldn't be enough to show that there can't be a countable union since there might as well be an uncountable union.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand what "countable union" means. I suggest reviewing all the relevant definitions.

Comment: So a countable union is a union of for example $\bigcup_{(n=1){n\in \mathbb{N}}}^\infty F_n$, right? So if the index set is countable then it's a countable union. Do you think that the union of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ is automatically countable? Then why would the Baire theorem specify it for countable unions? I'm sorry if I'm simply misunderstanding you.

Comment: Yes, "countable union" means the index set is countable. And if we write $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n$ then the index set is the natural numbers, which is of course countable.